# After form submit, insert data into Mysql and redirect user to an url mydomain.com/entries/last_inserted_id

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, url

After I submit a form I want the next things to happen:

1. Insert data into Mysql.
2. Redirect the user to a template I have (entries.php). This template shows all the data from the new inserted row in the table.
3. User should be redirected to url: `www.mydomain.com/entries/last_inserted_id` which will be my new template url address, where I show to the user all the data he submited in the form and **which can be later accessible by any user**.

How should I do this?

I am thinking like something www.mydomain.com/entries/`<?php get_last_id(); ?>`

Where `get_last_id()` will be a function which obtains the last id(which is auto increment) inserted.

Any ideeas on how to redirect a user to a url containing the id of the inserted row, based on my template which address is fixed like: entries.php Maybe some javscript code to help me?

Comment: About the last id thing, there is a function for that already called `mysqli_insert_id()`. more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php.  To redirect to another page **before ever printing anything** (as in `echo` or HTML) you may do `header("location: /path/to/file.php?last_id=$last_id");` and then `exit();`. That file should then use `$_GET['last_id']` to retrieve it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function in php.  Example:

```
$lastId = // whatever you're using to get last inserted id

header("Location: http://www.example.com/entries/$lastId");
```

*Note: make sure to use the funciton before outputting anything else.*

Comment: Yes, BUT, $last id is not an existent page. I think will return error NOT FOUND.

Comment: I think I need to tell my entries.php script that in order to show entries.php page, must have some string after www.domain.com/entries.php/some id here.

Comment: The example I've provided, based on your own, is using last id within the URL as a $_GET variable which would be extracted via .htaccess/etc.  If you want a more basic approach simply call "Location: http://www.example.com/entries.php?id=$lastId" in the header function as above.  You would then be capable of retrieving it on entries.php similar to $id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: I thought at this ideea in the first place, but at my last job where i worked, everytime I submited a form, it redirected me to www.mydomain.com/entries/12313, for example. I was trying to achieve exactly that, and not `.../entries?id=$lastid`. Probably the form would have create a webpage called by id...? But then on 2 million submits, would have been createad 2 million files, a lot of space used on hard drive.

Comment: What do you mean when you say  $_GET variable which would be extracted via .htaccess/etc ?

Comment: That's exactly why you need to create this file that will always retrieve information from your database _based on the ID passed by URL query_. So you're always redirecting to that **one and only** file that will read the ID using the `$_GET` variable. No files will be created upon submit if you do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/entries.php?id=$lastId");
```

this code should be work

Comment: I think I will try first to do some routing first, in order to achieve

www.mydomain.com/entries/last_inserted_id